# Tab completion for alias in OSX

Tags: bash, macos

I have an alias to change the directory as given below.

```sh
test(){
cd /Users/newuser/test/sub1/sub2/$1
}
```

So when running `test foldername`, it will change the directory to a respective subdirectory in `sub2`.

I used the below code for tab completion

```sh
_cdp () {
  … # code goes here
}
compdef _cdp cdp
```

as answered here [Alias to cd into a subdirectory with completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541900/how-to-set-up-alias-to-cd-into-a-subdirectory-with-completions). However, sourcing the profile triggered an error compdef not found.

NB: It is using a bash shell, not zsh.

How can I implement a tab completion for the alias so that, if a <kbd>Tab</kbd> is done after the alias, it will list the possible folders

Comment: Zsh completion and bash completion is not compatible. Write a bash completion function instead.

Comment: Btw.: I don't think using `test` as alias is a good idea, because `test` is already  a shell builtin. See `help test`.

Comment: @Cyrus - Thats not my alias name, that was just used as an example reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compdef` is a zsh command only. For bash use [`complete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion).

You can use *programmable completion* as in your example, where you specify a function (here `_cdp`) that generates the possible completions by adding them to the array `COMPREPLY+=(some new entries)`. Often, these entries are generated by `compgen`.

```
complete -F _cdp cdp
```

But in this case there is an easier option: Specify the possible completions directly using

```
IFS=$'\n' complete -W "$(cd /Users/newuser/test/sub1/sub2/ && compgen -G '*/')" cdp
```

Comment: Both of the answers didn't work. For the first one it made a tab completion but it triggered an error `-bash: cd: /Users/newuser/test/sub1/sub2/test: No such file or directory` , for the second option with a tab it completed printed the entire path like `test /Users/newuser/test/sub1/sub2/` but I require it to complete `test folder`

Comment: Oh right, I fixed the second command. However, the first error is obviously not an error in `complete -F` but in your `_cdp`/`cdp`.

Comment: I am not sure about the first one , and  I couldn't find an error, but the second one worked fine

Comment: is it possible to tab complete the sub directories ? That would make the answer versatile